# Forking, Signals and how they interact with global variables in C

Tags: c++, c, signals

I am trying to understand how fork()/Linux Kernel deals with global variables.

Given code:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t pid;
int counter = 2;
void handler1(int sig)
{
 counter = counter - 1;
 printf("%d", counter);
 exit(0);
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1); //Install Handler
    printf("%d", counter);     //Print Parent global variable
    pid = fork( );             //Fork(), child pid = 0, parent's pid = positive int.
    if (pid == 0)              //Parent skips this, child goes into infinite loop
    {
      while(1) {}; // simulate doing some work
    }
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);        //While child is the loop, parents calls to terminate the child. 
                               //Child will stop the infinite loop, and will not proceed any 
                               //Will it call handler1 ???

    wait(NULL);                //Wait for child to be ripped
                               //Will it call handler1 second time ???
    counter = counter + 1;     //This will surely increment global variable
    printf("%d", counter);
    exit(0);
}
```

The output is `2123`
How does Unix/Linux kernel deals with global variables after fork() and signal handlers are called ??? Do they get shared between child & parent ?

Another issues I have with this code, is how kill() & wait() will deal with global variables and what set will they use - parent's or child's ?? And will they call signal handler ???

Thanks !

Comment: Who is the perverse instructor who decided to end the semester with `fork`?

Comment: just plug the code into google search, it will come up in the old exams right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `fork()`, the entire process, including all global variables, is duplicated.  The child is an *exact* replica of the parent, except that it has a different PID, a different parent, and `fork()` returned 0.

A signal handler in the child will use the child's independent copy of the global variable.

The reason you're seeing `2` printed twice is that you haven't flushed standard output after printing it.  This is what happens:

- `counter` is equal to 2.
- Parent process executes `printf("%d", counter);`, which puts `"2"` into the `stdout` output buffer, but does *not* flush it.  No output appears yet.
- `fork()` is called, which duplicates the process.  There are now two copies of the `counter` variable, and both are set to 2.  There are also two instances of the `stdout` output buffer, both of which contain the string `"2"`.  No output appears yet.
- The parent sends `SIGUSR1` to the child, and blocks on `wait()`.
- The child executes `handler1()`, which decrements the child's copy of `counter` to 1, and puts `"1"` into the child's `stdout` output buffer (which now contains `"21"`).
- The child executes `exit(0)`, which as a side-effect flushes `stdout`.  The output `"21"` appears now, written by the child, and the child exits.
- `wait()` returns in the parent process.  The parent increments its copy of `counter` to 3, and then prints `"3"` into its `stdout` output buffer (which now contains `"23"`).
- The parent executes `exit(0)`, which as a side-effect flushes `stdout`.  The output `"23"` appears now, and the parent exits.

If you put `fflush(stdout);` before the `fork()`, the `2` will only be printed once, and the output will be `"213"`.  It is good practice to flush all buffered output streams before calling `fork()`.

Answer (score 5):

The child gets an *independent copy* of the global variables. The two copies are  *not shared*.

Answer (score 3):

`fork` creates **a copy** of the process in its current state. Nothing is shared except explicitly-mapped shared memory resources (anonymous shared maps, shared file maps, sysv shared memory blocks, and POSIX shared memory blocks).

You should also be aware that while the new process has its own copy of the file descriptor table, these file descriptors refer to the same "open file descriptions" in the kernel. They share a current seek position, among other things.

For further details, see:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html

Comment: The code segment is shared and possibly the constant data segment?

Comment: File descriptors are shared (as they are a resource that are held by the OS your application only contains a handle). File descriptors includes 'file system files' and 'sockets'.

Comment: File descriptors are not shared; they're copied, but they refer to the same underlying "open file descriptions" (this is the language POSIX uses), much like if you created them with `dup`.